# Joining multiple HTML table borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

My example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h4>Two rows and three columns:</h4>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>400</td>
  <td>500</td>
  <td>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
            <td>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            test
                        </td>
                        <td>    
                            wuut
                        </td>   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            test1
                        </td>
                        <td>    
                            wuut1
                        </td>   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            test2
                        </td>
                        <td>    
                            wuut2
                        </td>   
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>


<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>
```

You can just paste it here and see what it looks like : http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tables

What I need is that when tables are inside each other, tables have like joined borders. Only tables that data are separated.

At the moment the right bottom corner of table has like 3 layers of border, but that just looks ugly.

I tried using CSS:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

But this just removed cellspacing for borders :/

It should look like this, but this is with colspan/rowspan, which is too messy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h4>Two rows and three columns:</h4>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td colspan="3"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3">400</td>
  <td rowspan="3">500</td>
  <td rowspan="3">test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>wuut</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>test1</td>
  <td>test2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>wuut1</td>
  <td>wuut2</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are those `border="1"` doing there?

Comment: @ANeves : When I don't put it there, then it won't draw any lines between my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the program code that generates the markup so that there are no `border=1` attributes and there are `class` attributes for `td` elements, controlling borders around each cell. The `class` attribute would corresponds to CSS settings that set a border on selected sides of a cell, e.g. `<td class="left top">` with CSS code:

```
.left { border-left-style: solid } 
.top { border-top-style: solid }
```

The width and color of borders you can set in one rule, like:

```
td { border-width: 1px; border-color: #333; }
```

You should still set `table { border-collapse: collapse }` and probably set `padding: 0` on each cell that contains a table.

Comment: Isn't there a value, that automatically makes my tables borders collapse to eachother, when there is no value between borders?

Comment: @Jaanus, that's what `table { border-collapse: collapse }` does (and it also removes the spacing between cells).

Answer (score 1):

It’s a bit tricky, because the borders of nested tables are drawn separately. But you can tune things with some CSS3 so that they work in the desired way on modern browsers. (If you wish to achieve the effect on ancient browsers, too, you would need to scatter around a lot of `class` attributes.)

You need to remove the default cell spacing from (at least) cells containing tables. (The spacing between borders of inner and outer table come from the cells spacing.) This requires that each `td` that contains a `table` has a suitable `class` attribute, say `class=containsTable`, because in CSS you cannot refer to an element by its descendants (contents). Moreover, you need to selectively switch off top borders from the cells of the first row of any nested table, etc.:

```
.tableContainer { padding: 0; }
table table { border: none }
table table tr:first-child td { border-top: none; }
table table tr:last-child td { border-bottom: none; }
table table td:first-child { border-left: none; }
table table td:last-child { border-right: none; }
```

Comment: Hmm I added this css, but it just removed all table borders. Furthermore, I am taking my data from server from array, so I am just `for` looping over data and placing it to tables. Like nested `for` cycles, thats why I got tables inside tables. I can't manually edit single `<td>` element, I edited my question, to show what I want it to look like, does your solution do that? I wasn't able to get it the way I need.

Comment: Sorry, my code only works for simply nested tables. (If it does not work at all, you’re probably using a very old browser or IE in Quirks Mode.) Triple nesting would require even more complicated code. I will post a new answer, as the question has changed essentially.

Comment: I am using the latest chrome and don't use old browser at all. I just put my code with ur addition to : `http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tables`, all `<table>` elements changed to : `<table class="tableContainer">`. You sure it works for you? The question hasn't changed imo, basically I want it to have just joined borders. Like in the example in the end of initial questions, done with rowspans/colspans.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I think you need to explicitly add a first line `table td { border: solid 1px;`, or he won't get there himself.

Comment: @Jaanus, `class="tableContainer"` was to be set on a `td` cell that contains a `table` element, not on a `table` elements.

Comment: @Okay did it, now the 2nd and 3rd table don't have any borders inside.  Not exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<table style="border:0;">` wont show borders if that's what your looking for and you can also be specific about which side you want to display like for example:

```
 <table style="border-left:1px solid black;">
```

You can enter to the style border-(left,right,bottom,top):"pixels" "Type of border" "color".

```
<td style="border:0px;">
                            test
                        </td>
                        <td style="border:0px;">    
                            wuut
                        </td>   
                    </tr>
```

it wont show them. Or give them an ID and use `<style type="text/css">`

```
<style type="text/css">
#aa {border:0px;}
</style>
```

...

```
<td ID="aa">
```

...
if you can add ID="aa" to that loop then it should work.

Comment: Type to which ever <td> you would like not to be shown  <td style="border:0px;">

Comment: I am taking my data from server from array, so I am just for looping over data and placing it to tables. Like nested for cycles, thats why I got tables inside tables. I can't manually edit single <td> element, I edited my question, to show what I want it to look like, does your solution do that?

Comment: If you can put in an extra  <td ID="example"> to your loop and then at the begining type <style type="text/css">
#example {border:0px;}
</style>  then it should work

Comment: Doesn't that remove all borders?

Comment: Yea it removes where you put the same ID to <td> -s

Comment: Isn't there a method, parameter, that automatically makes my tables borders collapse to eachother, when there is no value between borders?